# DNS redirection from root domain to www for a heroku app

Tags: heroku, dns

I can't configure my DNS in order to redirect my root domain to www.domain for a Heroku app.

I'm using Vultr's DNS. The problem is Heroku does not provide IP address so I can't add an A record, nor a CNAM record to redirect root to www ([source](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/apex-domains)):

> DNS A-records require that an IP address be hard-coded into your
>   application’s DNS configuration. This prevents your infrastructure
>   provider from assigning your app a new IP address on your behalf when
>   adverse conditions arise and can have a serious impact to your app’s
>   uptime.
>
> A CNAME record does not require hard-coded IP addresses and allows
>   Heroku to manage the set of IPs associated with your domain. However,
>   CNAME records are not available at the zone apex and can’t be used to
>   configure root domains.

Here is my DNS configuration:
[image]

Thus, the SSL certificate fails in Heroku:
[image]

My question is: how can I easily redirect the root domain of my Heroku app to www.domain.com?

Thanks.

Comment: Providers which support CNAME-like functionality are listed in the [Custom Domains article](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/custom-domains#add-a-custom-root-domain).

Comment: Can't I do it with Vultr? I'm managing all my domains with their DNS, I would prefer to keep everything at the same place.

Comment: You should then probably ask them, but don't get your hopes up.

Answer (score -1):

ping with the DNS target you have got from Heroku. you will get the IP for that. Use that as Dns targe in vultr. worked for me.

example:

```
➜  ~ ping botletter.com.herokudns.com
PING botletter.com.herokudns.com (3.212.117.40): 56 data bytes
Request timeout for icmp_seq 0
Request timeout for icmp_seq 1
```

Here use 3.212.117.40 IP in vultr DNS target

Comment: Heroku's IPs, by default are dynamic. So no, this will fail as soon as the IP changes.
You can use add-ons such as Fixie to get a list of static IP addresses.
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/fixie